# Fitting data points to a line on a semi-log plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a semi-log plot (log on the x-axis) that includes error bars. I'm trying to fit a line through the data points. So far I've tried plotting my data and a separate line and adjusting the intercepts of the line until it was (sorta) within my data. This felt too primitive. So now I'm trying to do this based off of previous posts

```
y0=-12
m=1
f(x) = y0 + m*log(x)
fit f(x) "av_bngc6522_Hband_chi1p5_IR_10" using 29:35:33:39 w xyerrorbars via m,y0
```

Gnuplot is saying "Need via and either parameter list or file". I don't really know what this means and I'm sure my syntax is off. Need some help.

Comment: Can you please show an example datafile?  Something with ~10 points would be perfect for us to play around with ...

Answer (score 1):

`with xyerrorbars` is a plotting style and can't be used for fitting. And you can only have one error value, which is assumed to be the standard deviation of the `z` value, see `help fit`. The independent variable `x` can't have an associated error value.

You script must look like this: (adapt the column numbers)

```
y0=-12
m=1
f(x) = y0 + m*log(x)
fit f(x) "av_bngc6522_Hband_chi1p5_IR_10" using 29:35:39 via m,y0
```